# Does any continuous function from the open unit interval $(0,1)$ to itself has a fixed point?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, fixed-point-theorems

I know that the result is true for closed interval $[0,1]$ by using intermediate value property.

But in the case where we consider open interval $(0,1)$ does the solution change?

Comment: Similarly, it's also false for $(0,1]$ (though it won't be a bijection) by the function $x\mapsto\frac x2$.

Comment: That's nice. :)

Comment: Yes, I understood that. :) Hence the result will be true only for closed intervals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try $x\mapsto x^2$ for a counterexample.